# I can't get my one div to float left and the other right

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS and am working through my courses in Web Design and have come across one of my pages not allowing me to float divs the way i want to. My goal is to have one div float left and the other flost right next to each other. I can't get the first div to float left but I can get the second div to float right but it stays underneath the first div. I feel like I'm missing something simple but I just can't figure it out.

```css
#services {
  float: left;
}
#contact {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="services">
    <h2>Services</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, natoque pharetra. Neque vulputate wisi in. Per blandit viverra parturient vitae, maecenas orci turpis scelerisque odio, viverra enim. Condimentum id neque lobortis donec mauris, ridiculus nonummy vel massa vestibulum est.
      Blandit non convallis primis conubia est varius, velit a parturient, dapibus dictumst eu aptent maecenas elit sodales, vel imperdiet enim vulputate lorem. Vel dictumst, lacus vel cum tempor suspendisse tellus, consectetuer vel orci, metus pellentesque,
      nulla hac convallis nonummy tempus. Sollicitudin pulvinar eget scelerisque libero, nullam dis. Ipsum sit malesuada odio nisl. Amet donec, cursus vulputate eget mattis. Praesent velit dui ligula malesuada parturient tincidunt. Nisl ligula condimentum
      id. Consectetuer arcu, elit massa nostra diam ut augue, vel dolor sollicitudin molestie.</p>

    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div id="contact">

    <h2>Contact Us</h2>

    <p>Contact Name
      <br>Line 1
      <br>Line 2
      <br>Post Code
      <br>
      <a id="mobile" href="tel:111-123-4567">(111) 123-4567</a>
      <span id="desktop">(111) 123-4567</span>
      <br>
      <a href="mailto:info@info.com">info@info.com</a>
    </p>
    <br>
  </div>
</main>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the two divs on side of each other, you need to set the first div (#services) width less than 100% so that the other div can fit in the same row, otherwise the whole row is occupied by that div itself.
Made modification only to CSS. 
The modified code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/admL7ss3/

```
#services {
  float: left;
  width:50%;
  valign:top;
}
#contact {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
h2{
  margin-top:0px;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple just wasn't working for me at the time!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define width for them. Such that sum of their width is 100%. If you don't want them to stretch to much then you can use `max-width` property.

These floated div should not have any margin but you can give padding to them. Also if you are using `border` property for any of them then don't forget to use `box-sizing:border-box;`, otherwise the left-one will push th right-one down. I just used border in this example to show this.

Here's the example:

```css
#services{
  float:left;
  width:70%;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#contact{
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  width:30%;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<main>
           <div id="services">
                <h2>Services</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, natoque pharetra. Neque vulputate wisi in. Per blandit viverra parturient vitae, maecenas orci turpis scelerisque odio, viverra enim. Condimentum id neque lobortis donec mauris, ridiculus nonummy vel massa vestibulum est. Blandit non convallis primis conubia est varius, velit a parturient, dapibus dictumst eu aptent maecenas elit sodales, vel imperdiet enim vulputate lorem. Vel dictumst, lacus vel cum tempor suspendisse tellus, consectetuer vel orci, metus pellentesque, nulla hac convallis nonummy tempus. Sollicitudin pulvinar eget scelerisque libero, nullam dis. Ipsum sit malesuada odio nisl. Amet donec, cursus vulputate eget mattis. Praesent velit dui ligula malesuada parturient tincidunt. Nisl ligula condimentum id. Consectetuer arcu, elit massa nostra diam ut augue, vel dolor sollicitudin molestie.</p>

                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            <div id="contact">

                <h2>Contact Us</h2>

                <p>Contact Name<br>
                Line 1<br>
                Line 2<br>
                Post Code<br>
                <a id="mobile" href="tel:111-123-4567">(111) 123-4567</a>
                <span id="desktop">(111) 123-4567</span><br>
                <a href="mailto:info@info.com">info@info.com</a>
                </p><br>
            </div>
        </main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the tips :) It's always the simple things I seem to miss, I'm sure with more practice I'll get the hang of it!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the service and contact div under the main area in 1 row. You must give that first, Finally work the float left or right attribute.